# regex pattern not matching at start of the line

Tags: php, regex

I have this pattern:

```
/([^>'"])(http|ftp)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/
```

when using this as a subject:

```
http://www.google.com <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a> http://www.google.com
```

It matches the last `http://www.google.com` but not the first one at the start of the line. How can I get it to match the first one at the start of the line too? (and continue to not match inside the anchor tag)

Answer (score 1):

It's because `[^'">]` means any *one* character that isn' `'`, `"` or `>`. There is no one character before the `http` at the start of the line, which is why it's not matching.

One possibility (not necessarily the best), is to use something like:

```
(([^'">])(http))|(^http)
```

(either of two possible patterns). This basically means to give me all those you currently specify *as well as* "http" at the start of the line.

I don't doubt there are trickier ways to do this with the more advanced regex features like look-ahead, negative look-behind or the little known surreptitious look-under <sup>(a)</sup>, but I prefer simplicity most of the time.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Some features alluded to in this answer may not, in fact, exist :-)

Comment: This will match the ones inside the anchor tag though so it is not useful :(

Answer (score 1):

`/(^|[^>'"])(http|ftp)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/` will do it for you. `^` inside `[]` will negate the rest of the characters. You have to keep `^` at the starting of the regex and outside of `[]` to match the start of the line

Comment: This one also matches inside the anchor tag.

Comment: I just ran and i got the match for only first google and fourth google ..i dont think it matches inside the anchor. Can you give a link to the fiddle where you are getting match inside the anchor. I just made a change to the regex in the start which is (^|[^>'"]) which just adds the start of line or condition to the regex you gave.

Comment: Here is the fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/F2v7W/ ...it prints `["http://www.google1.com", " http://www.google4.com"]` on the console.

Comment: Hmm when testing with this site: http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ I was getting matches inside the anchors, but others give me good results. Weird. Go to the link and paste your regex and `http://www.google.com <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a> http://www.google.com` as the subject. However here: http://regexr.com?2uqmu with global on it works

Comment: Yes, you need to have global on for matching the entire input. Otherwise it would stop after the first match.

Answer (score -1):

try `([^'">])?(http)` (untested)